# CMD FOR /F to search mismatches inside between files

Tags: windows, shell, for-loop, cmd

Stuck and desperate to parse and compare two or more CSV log files from multiple servers then output mismatches.

*The actual batch script will use %%G values but for now I'm directly tweaking inside the shell. We've also set delayed expansion using SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion*

```
    FOR /F "tokens=1,2,3,4,5 delims=," %G IN (AnyChangesList.txt) DO FIND /I "%G" SourceLIST.txt if %errorlevel% EQU 1 echo MISMATCH
```

I have to find discrepancies between two or more well structured CSV logs.
 Also scoured the SS64.com site for help and advanced it a little further but still getting errors.

I'm forced to use the CMD shell for too many reasons to list here since I'm certain there are numerous solutions to achieve the objective.

**Sample logs AnyChangesList.txt**

USER ID,Business Unit,Work State,Home State,Status
00100,ACS,REG,**MARYLAND**,Washington,Active Start,Term during,03/19/2012,11/29/2015

**Sample logs SourceLIST.txt**

USER ID,Business Unit,Work State,Home State,Status
00100,ACS,REG,**Oregon**,Washington,Active Start,Term during,03/19/2012,11/29/2015

The errors are perplexing me to my knowledge limits:

---------- SOURCELIST.TXT
File not found - IF
File not found - 1
File not found - EQU
File not found - 0
File not found - ECHO
File not found - MISMATCH

Comment: Have you tried the `FC` command? Use `FC /?` to read about it.

Comment: FC is for exacting file comparisons like a poor hash sum utility, 

I need to parse one CSV log file with the entries of differing CSV log files
.

I'm parsing the Sourcelist for any comparisons